# What is a top-level statement in Python?

Tags: python

In the Python Guide's chapter on [project structure](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/structure.html), the term "top-level statement" is brought up a few times. I'm not sure exactly what this refers to. My guess is it's any variable declarations that happen outside of any functions or class methods that fire as soon as a module is loaded. Is this correct? Does it also include a module's `import` statements?

Comment: I assume it would include not just imports and declarations, but any code that occurs outside functions and classes.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It's not just variable declarations (and there aren't any variable declarations anyway). It's pretty much anything that starts at indentation level 0.

```
import sys         # top-level

3 + 4              # top-level

x = 0              # top-level

def f():           # top-level
    import os      # not top-level!
    return 3       # not top-level

if x:              # top-level
    print 3        # not top-level
else:
    print 4        # not top-level, but executes as part of an if statement
                   # that is top-level

class TopLevel(object): # top-level
    x = 3          # not top-level, but executes as part of the class statement
    def foo(self): # not top-level, but executes as part of the class statement
        print 5    # not top-level
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's the first mention of "top-level statement":

> Once modu.py is found, the Python interpreter will execute the module in an isolated scope. Any top-level statement in modu.py will be executed, including other imports if any. Function and class definitions are stored in the module’s dictionary.

This makes it clear that what they really mean is "things that are interpreted at `import` time".

While it's not terribly helpful directly, the [Python documentation itself](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/toplevel_components.html) also uses the phrase "top-level" (components, which then means "statements" in this context).

Note that this module:

```
"""a python module, spam.py"""

def spam():
    return "spam"

class Spam(object):
    pass
```

has two statements in it, the `def` and the `class`.  These are both *executed* at import time.  These definitions are compound statements (see [`def`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) and [`class`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#class-definitions) descriptions).  If there are decorators attached to a top-level `def`, that adds even more top-level things to run.  (See also [user2357112's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18138250/1256452): running a `class` statement invokes more internal workings.)

Add an `import sys` at the top and you've added a third statement, which imports `sys`.  However, if you add this:

```
def ham(eggs):
    import os
    return os.path.basename(eggs)
```

you have still only added one statement, the `def ham`, to the top-level stuff.  It's when `ham` itself is executed (called) that the `import os` will be run.

Answer (score 1):

In python, the statements which are not indented are called a top-level statement. Internally python gives a special name to top-level statement s as `__main__`.