# How to avoid top level statements in print function in python for the following program?

Tags: python

```
def greet(val):
  print('Hello,'+' '+val+'!')
  return val
greet( 'World')
```

How to avoid top level statements in print function?

Comment: what do you mean by top level statements?

Comment: And why do you return `val`?

Comment: Why use `'Hello,'+' '+...` instead of `'Hello, ' +...`?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18138166/what-is-a-top-level-statement-in-python) should explain what a top level statement is.

Comment: Actually when i call the function greet with the word 'World', i must get an output as Hello, World! But my print statement should not contain top level statements.